# An $O(n^2\log^c{n})$ algorithm for matrix multiplication in this paper?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, matrix-product

In the newest version of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04208) by Yijie Han, the author claims that matrix multiplication can be solved by an $\tilde{O}(n^2)$ algorithm. It should be a big result, but it is still in arxiv and no one else ever cited it. I've tried to read it and the basic idea is an $O(\log^c{n})$ computation for inner product where $c$ is an constant, which results in an $O(n^2\log^c{n})$ algorithm for matrix multiplication.

The details in this paper are too complicated to be fully understand, have anyone checked the correctness of this paper or read this paper?

Comment: Probably people gave up. Notice that this paper 16 different versions and there was an error in each of the versions. Plus the paper seems to be poorly written, there are no lemmas inside etc.

Comment: On page 20 of the current version, the author writes: *"Also I have a vague feeling that the matrix multiplication algorithm presented in this paper may have implications to the NP-complete problems."*

Comment: Abstract states inner product in O(1) which means he is ignoring sizes of words.

Comment: @1.. what do you mean by that? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: [Current](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/mathematicians) [state of the art](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05846).

Comment: @J.G. I knew the laser method but the Han's paper uses a totally different technology, which I have seen nowhere.